# Navigation drawer android studio error "expected start or end tag Affected Modules: app" al agregar activity en proyecto ya creado

Tags: xml, navigation, android-manifest

Buenas noches quería consultar si es posible agregar un navigation drawer en un proyecto ya existente porque cuando lo hago desde new activity me da el siguiente error:

> ERROR: Failed to parse XML in
>   D:\andoid\SmartLibraryreader\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
>   ParseError at [row,col]:[27,9] Message: expected start or end tag
>   Affected Modules: app

Este es mi AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".BienvenidaActivity">
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        // La actividad para ver los pdf por ahora es la segunda en ejecutarse.
    </activity>



    </application>
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Agrega lo que estas agregando a tu AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: <activity android:name=".BienvenidaActivity">
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        // La actividad para ver los pdf por ahora es la segunda en ejecutarse.
    </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>

Comment: Muchas gracias, empece otro proyecto de con la actividar navigation drawer y logre crear el menu, ahora estoy viendo porque como soy nuevo no tengo claro como hago para que una actividad que me funcionaba bien que era mostrar un listado de archivos de mi sd en mi actividad ahora aparezca en un fragment siempre que entre.

Comment: Ok @Eder agregue una respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que indica el mensaje:

> Message: expected start or end tag Affected Modules: app

es que tienes un tag incorrecto que se esta cerrando incorrectamente, y este problema lo puedes ver aquí:

```
<activity android:name=".BienvenidaActivity">
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

el tag activity esta incorrectamente cerrado debe ser:

```
<activity android:name=".BienvenidaActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias solucionado el problema.